# Do I need to explicitly release FullHttpRequest.content().copy()?

Tags: java, http, memory-leaks, netty

I have the following code to copy incoming `FullHttpRequest` content into separate `ByteBuf` to pass it to another thread for processing:

```
final ByteBuf requestContent;
requestContent = httpRequest.content().copy();
```

(i need to create a copy because access to original buffer from other thread will raise `IllegalReferenceCountException` )

Channel init method looks like the following:

```
ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(maxRequestSize));
p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());

p.addLast(httpServerHandler);
```

(no explicit bytebuf pools or anything)

The question is: Where `ByteBuf` copy is created? Is it created in JVM heap (and will be `GC`'ed automatically by JVM) or is it created somewhere inside netty pools, waiting for explicit *release* and creating memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Netty reference](http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#wiki-h2-10) says that byte buffers have to be released explicitly in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Why netty doesn't report this ByteBuf as memory leak then? I.e. I've added -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=paranoid to JVM arguments and expect this copied buffer to be reported. But console is empty...